# powershell: use variable with wildcard with get-aduser

Tags: powershell

powershell newbie here. I am building a simple bit of code to help me find user's by entering letters of user names. How do I get a wildcard to work w/ a variable?
this works:

```
$name=read-host -prompt "enter user's first or last initial"
$userInput=get-aduser -f {givenname -like 'A*' } 
cmd /c echo "output: $userInput"
```

this does not:

```
$name=read-host -prompt "enter user's first or last initial"
$userInput=get-aduser -f {givenname -like '$name*' } 
cmd /c echo "output: $userInput"
```

The first bit of code delivers a list of users with "A" in their name. Any suggestions woudl be appreciated. thanks

Comment: You can probably use `Write-Host` in place of `cmd /c echo` for the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
$lastname = "smith"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(Sn=*$lastname*))"
```

Returns a list of users whose last name (surname) matches the search pattern of `*smith*`, so it will return Haysmith, Smithwood, McSmithers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I am getting this error with that code: Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(Sn=*$lastnam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The search filter cannot be recognized,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: That will happen if the variable has not been created and assigned a value.  I.E. you do not have $lastname="smith" above the call.

Comment: ah yes of course...a newbie I am. That worked thanks. Now to work on a UI, formatting and other things.

Answer (score 0):

When single quotation marks are used, escape characters and automatic string replacement (e.g. using a variable inside the string) are eliminated.

While Ryan Ries answer will work with the `-LDAPFilter` parameter, to work with the `-Filter` parameter you will have to concatenate or use escape characters.

Using escape characters (An apostrophe before the character):

```
$userInput=get-aduser -f "GivenName -like `"$name*`""
```

Using string concatenation:

```
$userInput=get-aduser -f ('GivenName -like "' + $name + '*"')
```

Better readability:

```
$name = read-host -prompt "enter user's first or last initial"
$filter = 'GivenName -like "' + $name + '*"'
$userInput = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter
```

Comment: thanks, I was wondering how it would play out with -filter